# Is a webcam feed inside of emacs possible?

Tags: emacs

I want to live stream me coding on TwitchTV. Back in my vim days, I would open up several terminals and leave a small hole in the corner to put a quicktime webcam display so that my screen recorder would capture my face. What I would like is the ability to embed a webcam feed into a buffer of emacs so that it will be integrated with emacs tiling ability. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: If you can't get it to work within Emacs, why not try setting your webcam preview window to be "Always on top"? Should be pretty easy using any *nix window manager, and there are utilities to do it in Windows, e.g. http://www.pcworld.com/article/218511/Windows.html

Comment: Emacs 25 is bringing support for embedding arbitrary GTK+ widgets in Emacs (including Webkit), so this should be much simpler soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take my answer with a grain of salt, it's untested and I'm not sure if it works, and it certainly won't do audio.

1. Create a live-streaming .gif file from your video stream:

   `git clone https://github.com/jbochi/gifstreaming`
   `cd gifstreaming`
   `mkdir input`
   `mkdir parts`
   `ffmpeg -re -i rtmp:///dev/video0 -pix_fmt pal8 -s 159x97 -r 10 input/in%d.gif &`
   `python transform.py`
   `node server.js`

https://github.com/jbochi/gifstreaming

2. Open a buffer with the image displayed inline using the emacs web browser:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `eww` <kbd>RET</kbd> `http://localhost:8080/` <kbd>RET</kbd>

---

Alternatively, you could try streaming directly from your webcam without the gif step, but I doubt `eww` can display video files inline.

http://www.area536.com/projects/streaming-video/